# How to fill combobox on DropDownOpened

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, eventtrigger

i have to fill the dropdown box when dropdown is open. I mean i click on the arrow and the VM have to fill it an then Open. I have a ObservableCollection of strings to fill in the combobox. The MVM is also INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ServersBox"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Height="23" IsEditable="True" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" 
        IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="False" StaysOpenOnEdit="True" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableSqlServer}"  
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSqlServer}" Text="{Binding newServer, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="261">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="DropDownOpened" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=ServersBox}">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnDropDownOpened}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>


public MigratorSqlViewModel(Migrator _m)
{
    _setdropDownCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(OnDropDownOpened);
}
private RelayCommand<object> _setdropDownCommand;
public RelayCommand<object> SetdropDownCommand
{
    get {return _setdropDownCommand; }
    set { _setdropDownCommand = value; }
}

public void OnDropDownOpened(object obj)
{

    AvailableSqlServer = _Migrator.getServer();

}

public ObservableCollection<string> AvailableSqlServer
{
    set
    {
        this._availableSqlServer = value;
        _Migrator.AvailableSqlServer = _availableSqlServer;
        OnPropertyChanged("AvailableSqlServer");
    }
    get { return _availableSqlServer; }
}
```

It happens nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code you command name `SetdropDownCommand` but you bound `OnDropDownOpened`. So please bind the command correctly as follows.

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SetdropDownCommand}" />
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working. You saved my day. Thanks a lot)))

Comment: @Bird75 Most Welcome :-)

Comment: How can I make it that even I dropdown the List is loaded but so that the conbobox doesn't select the first Item. I mean that without to choose something by a user the selected item is empty.

Comment: try SelectedSqlServer=AvailableSqlServer.FirstOrDefault() after AvailableSqlServer = _Migrator.getServer();

Comment: it select the first item in the list and set it into the combobox. I think it must be somethin in the Combobox Propperty "selectetItem".

Comment: if not try this in xaml SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSqlServer, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}". Also you need call  OnPropertyChanged("SelectedSqlServer");

Comment: in both cases it select the first string in the list and put it into the combobox as Selected Item and I want that if the user have not choose something in the combobox the selected item remains empty

Comment: @Bird75 I am not getting you clearly. Can you tell me your requirement clearly?

Comment: I mean if I drop the combobog i get a list...now the combobox set as selectedItem the first value in the lis. I want thet the selectetItem will be set only wenn i choose something from the list, if not the selectetIem has to be empty.

Comment: You can set SelectedSqlServer=null or empty and remove SelectedSqlServer=AvailableSqlServer.FirstOrDefault() this line